# How do I push to the current git branch on remote, and have changes reflected immediately?

Tags: git

I've got a 2 web servers, one testing and one live. Both have their codebases managed with git.

I develop on the testing server, then push the changes from a master branch on the testing server to the live server with `git push`. However, at the moment I then have to log in to the live server and run `git reset --hard` for the changes to be reflected in the live code.

The warning message git displays when I push suggests changing the setting of `receive.denyCurrentBranch` to change how this push is handled. However, as I understand, I can either have it refuse the push, accept it with a warning and require a `git reset`, or accept it with no warning and require a `git reset`. Can I have it accept the push an **not** require the reset?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're pushing into a non-bare repo (that is, one that has a copy of the repo's files checked out on-disk). You can push into it, but Git won't automatically update the working-copy files without a `git reset` (or `git checkout`). You could use a post-receive hook to do the checking out automatically, though -- there's a good how-to available [here](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto).

Answer (score 0):

mipadi is right that you really need to have a bare repo to pull from on your production server. If you're not comfortable with a post-commit hook (lots of people aren't). You can create a cron job on that server that runs
    git pull origin master
every half hour or so.

Comment: A cron job wouldn't quite solve my problem - I still only want changes to be pushed to the live server on my explicit command.
Perhaps having `git reset --hard` running on a cron job would work, but the hook seems like a more elegant solution.

Comment: yeah, for sure, a hook is the best way to go. Some people are intimidated by writing them so I wanted to show an alternative for good of the order