# How to reset staged changes on the remote after a push?

Tags: git

I have two non-bare git repositories, one a local machine in which I develop and the second on a server, on which I build. In the local repository I have a post-commit hook with "git push -f server". Each time I commit on a local machine, changes are pushed to the server.
Unfortunately, on the remote git stages a "revert" of my changes. I have to do a "git reset HEAD --hard" on the server manually, which is quite annoying. How can I tell git to accept changes without staging a revert or how can I automatically do a reset on the server? I have tried to add a post-receive hook on the server, but it doesn't work.

I have found a similar question [How do I push to the current git branch on remote, and have changes reflected immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523008/how-do-i-push-to-the-current-git-branch-on-remote-and-have-changes-reflected-im) , but it did not help (

Comment: It turned out be quite simple:

do not forget to give hooks executable rights!

Works fine now)

Answer (score 0):

You have the choice of:

- pushing directly to a non-bare repo, in which case you need a post-receive hook to do checkout the new `HEAD` as described in "[Using Git to manage a web site](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto)" and referenced in "[Git Post-Receive Hook for Website Staging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838727/git-post-receive-hook-for-website-staging)".
  As you noted, giving execution right to the hook is key.

```
    $ cat > hooks/post-receive
    #!/bin/sh
    GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org git checkout -f
    $ chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

- or, you could push to a bare repo, and have an hook switching to the live non-bare repo, *pulling* the new commits from the bare repo:
  See "[Git submodule on remote bare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448682/git-submodule-on-remote-bare/9448794#9448794)" (you can ignore the submodule aspect)

I tend to favor the second approach, which seems "cleaner" than directly changing `HEAD` on a non-bare repo.

Comment: Thanks, VonC.
Unfortunately post-receive hook on the server is very slow, because it seems to be executed on a local machine, which means files are accessed over the network. Project is quite huge and reset takes a couple of minutes.
"git config receive.denyCurrentBranch warn" does not make any difference.

Comment: @YuriyKulikov that shouldn't be the case for a post-receive set on a bare repo, because said bare repo is just on the same box than the live non-bare repo. No network invoved.